# Uma div cobrir a tela inteira no CSS

Tags: css

Eu tenho um painel onde há um button que puxa uma função que demora um tempo para executar, aí queria colocar uma img de load e background com alpha, mais só está pegando uma parte da tela igual ao print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código CSS e HTML:

```css
 .load { 
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100vw;//ja tentei usando 100% tbm
  height: 100vh;//ja tentei usando 100% tbm
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .load img{
  margin: auto auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="load"><img src="load.gif"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue com as propriedades top, right, bottom e left, todas com valor `0`.

Para centralizar a imagem você pode usar `transform` com top, left e position, ou usar flexbox.

**Com transform:**

```css
.load { 
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .load img{
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="load"><img src="load.gif"></div>
```

**Com flexbox:**

```css
.load { 
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="load"><img src="load.gif"></div>
```

Comment: Deu certo, desconhecia disso rs, obrigado cara. Assim que liberar eu coloco como resolvido

Comment: Valeu jovem!...

Answer (score 3):

Segue um exemplo, usei `display:flex` no pai para a imagem ficar alinhada no centro com `margin:auto`

Como o elemento tem `position:fixed` ele é relativo a janela, e vc precisa alinha-lo para os `100vh/vw` cobrir totalmente o *viewport*, para isso coloquei `top` e `left` como `0`

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.load { 
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
 }
 .load img{
  margin: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="load">
  <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
</div>
```

Comment: é melhor usar % ou vh/vw?

Comment: No seu caso eu iria de vh/vw pois é referente ao viewport, para garantir que realmente vai cobrir toda a área visível!

Comment: obrigado por tirar minhas duvidas